# Use token generated in the google API console to communicate with the google play apis

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-play

I'm building a web game, and I'd like to make use of [google's game services](http://developers.google.com/games/services) such as high scores. When I do this using the client_id of my [api console](http://developers.google.com/console) project, it tells me that there is no app linked to this api consumer.

In the Google Play [games publisher console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish), it says that my game is linked to my apis console project, but when I create a linked app, it still asked me to create a new oauth2 consumer id and secret. So I did it, entering the exact same name project name, and now I have 2 api console projects with the same name. I had the original proejct configured with other apis I use.

Do I need to just delete my original apis console project, and just configure the new project, the same way I had the original project configured? Or is there a way to use an existing apis console project and associate that with a linked app?

Also, if the game information in the game publishing console tells me that the game has been linked to the original project, why doesn't it just associate the linked app with that project, and the oauth credentials that it had obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Really basic and you probably have, but have you enabled the Google Play Games Services API in API access?